# How to authorise (with OAuth 2.0) in JMeter having sharepoint online app?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jmeter, sharepoint-online, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-5.0

I have recorded scripts for all test cases, and run all test cases due to the OAuth  2.0 it is failing all of the test cases.
Now I have to authenticate OAuth 2.0 in JMeter, I have following information:

`client_id, response_mode, protectedtokena, response_type, resources, scope, nonce,redirect_uri,wsucxt, cobrandid, client-request-id`.

Comment: any comments about the answer?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add (or parametrize) parameter `Authorization` in your HTTP Header Manager. Add `Bearer ${AuthToken}` value. You should parse that token from previouse request.
2. Check this guide about [How to parse auth token](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/05/test-rest-apis-authentication-using-jmeter/)

Comment: [{"user_id":=====,
"network_id":====,
"network_permalink":"ncr.com",
"network_name":"NCRCorporation",
"network_canonical":true,
"network_primary":true,
"token":"=============",
"secret":"===============",
"view_members":true,
"view_groups":true,"view_messages":true,
"view_subscriptions":true,
"modify_subscriptions":true,
"modify_messages":true,
"view_tags":true,
"created_at":"2018/10/16 05:17:25 +0000",
"authorized_at":"2018/10/16 05:17:25 +0000",
"expires_at":null
}]

Comment: Could you provide screenshots of your current Test Plan and result of one test run with one Thread in View Result Tree?

Comment: @surenderpal I've edited my answer, check this two steps.

Comment: @Yangunaev I'm sharing the screenshot of the test but one question I'm getting the token at the end of the of the script then how should I automate it for the beginning of the script.https://imgur.com/a/cmJicPk

Comment: As shown on you screen, you recorded this tokens once. For the next session they will be different. That's why your next test runs fails.
You should not send id_token and other parameters as constant.
You need to parse theirs values from the previous requests, such login.
Probably it is in auth\sso request - you should add ReExp Extractor to it.
Check the 2nd link at my answer and this link to clarification:
https://ecosmobian.wordpress.com/2017/01/11/handling-bearer-token-for-web-application-in-jmeter/